# Не получается переместить окно (pygetwindow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

```
import ctypes

import pygetwindow as gw
import keyboard
import pyautogui

class Main:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        keyboard.add_hotkey('f10', self.center_active_window)
        keyboard.wait()

    def get_taskbar_size(self):
        # Создаем структуру RECT
        rect = ctypes.wintypes.RECT()
        # Получаем дескриптор окна панели задач
        taskbar = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
        # Получаем размеры панели задач
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowRect(taskbar, ctypes.byref(rect))
        # Возвращаем высоту панели задач
        return rect.bottom - rect.top

    def center_active_window(self):
        # Получаем активное окно
        active_window = gw.getActiveWindow()

        # Получаем размеры экрана
        screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

        # Вычитаем высоту панели задач из высоты экрана
        screen_height -= self.get_taskbar_size()

        # Проверяем, открыто ли окно "copilot"
        copilot_windows = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('copilot')
        if copilot_windows:
            # Если окно "copilot" открыто, вычитаем его ширину из ширины экрана
            screen_width -= copilot_windows[0].width

        # Вычисляем координаты для центрирования окна
        old_x = active_window._getWindowRect().left
        old_y = active_window._getWindowRect().top

        new_x = (screen_width - active_window.width) // 2
        new_y = (screen_height - active_window.height) // 2

        for px_x, px_y in (range(old_x, new_x, 7), range(old_y, new_y, 7)):  # Пробовал через zip()
            active_window.moveTo(px_x, px_y) # Вот здесь проблема, окно не перемещается


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код пытается переместить окно по одному пикселю за каждую итерацию цикла. Однако, метод `moveTo` из библиотеки `pygetwindow` может не успевать обрабатывать такое большое количество операций за короткое время.

Вместо этого, вы можете просто переместить окно на новые координаты сразу, без использования цикла.

```
import ctypes

import pygetwindow as gw
import keyboard
import pyautogui

class Main:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        keyboard.add_hotkey('f10', self.center_active_window)
        keyboard.wait()

    def get_taskbar_size(self):
        # Создаем структуру RECT
        rect = ctypes.wintypes.RECT()
        # Получаем дескриптор окна панели задач
        taskbar = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
        # Получаем размеры панели задач
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowRect(taskbar, ctypes.byref(rect))
        # Возвращаем высоту панели задач
        return rect.bottom - rect.top

    def center_active_window(self):
        # Получаем активное окно
        active_window = gw.getActiveWindow()

        # Получаем размеры экрана
        screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

        # Вычитаем высоту панели задач из высоты экрана
        screen_height -= self.get_taskbar_size()

        # Проверяем, открыто ли окно "copilot"
        copilot_windows = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('copilot')
        if copilot_windows:
            # Если окно "copilot" открыто, вычитаем его ширину из ширины экрана
            screen_width -= copilot_windows[0].width

        # Вычисляем координаты для центрирования окна
        new_x = (screen_width - active_window.width) // 2
        new_y = (screen_height - active_window.height) // 2

        # Перемещаем окно на новые координаты
        active_window.moveTo(new_x, new_y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Извините, но это не решение моей проблемы, мне нужна анимация перемещения окна. Хочу подметить, что окно перемещается не на 1 пкс, а на 7 вправо и на 7 вниз

Answer (score 0):

@KiryxaKart,  вы пытаетесь одновременно итерироваться по двум диапазонам. Однако написанный вами код не будет работать так, как вы ожидаете. Функция `range()` генерирует последовательность чисел от начального значения до конечного значения с указанным шагом. Когда вы используете две функции `range()`, они не будут итерироваться параллельно. Вместо этого второй `range()` будет итерироваться для каждого элемента первого `range()`. Если вы хотите итерироваться по двум диапазонам одновременно, вы можете использовать функцию `zip()`.

Ваш код пытается переместить окно на каждой итерации цикла, но это не работает, потому что `moveTo` не обновляет положение окна сразу. Вместо этого, он отправляет сообщение операционной системе, которое будет обработано позже.

Вы можете добавить небольшую задержку после каждого вызова `moveTo`, чтобы дать системе время на обработку сообщения.

```
import ctypes
import time

import pygetwindow as gw
import keyboard
import pyautogui

class Main:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        keyboard.add_hotkey('f10', self.center_active_window)
        keyboard.wait()

    def get_taskbar_size(self):
        # Создаем структуру RECT
        rect = ctypes.wintypes.RECT()
        # Получаем дескриптор окна панели задач
        taskbar = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
        # Получаем размеры панели задач
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowRect(taskbar, ctypes.byref(rect))
        # Возвращаем высоту панели задач
        return rect.bottom - rect.top

    def center_active_window(self):
        # Получаем активное окно
        active_window = gw.getActiveWindow()

        # Получаем размеры экрана
        screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

        # Вычитаем высоту панели задач из высоты экрана
        screen_height -= self.get_taskbar_size()

        # Проверяем, открыто ли окно "copilot"
        copilot_windows = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('copilot')
        if copilot_windows:
            # Если окно "copilot" открыто, вычитаем его ширину из ширины экрана
            screen_width -= copilot_windows[0].width

        # Вычисляем координаты для центрирования окна
        old_x = active_window._getWindowRect().left
        old_y = active_window._getWindowRect().top

        new_x = (screen_width - active_window.width) // 2
        new_y = (screen_height - active_window.height) // 2

        for px_x, px_y in zip(range(old_x, new_x, 7), range(old_y, new_y, 7)):
            active_window.moveTo(px_x, px_y)
            time.sleep(0.01)  # Добавляем задержку

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```